# Android default JSON example

Tags: android, json

Android has default JSON support with import org.json. Is there any simple example of serializing and deserializing this way? Are there any advanced options for serializing/deserializing like references or inheritance?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [first google hit](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/).

What do you mean with *serializing/deserializing like references or inheritance*?
JSON is not a class serialization format like the build-in Java serialization. It's a pure and simple data exchange format, check the [format definition](http://www.json.org/).

Comment: Thanks, I have finaly made it, but in this way, if I want to use some complex class serialization, I will have to move to another solutions, like JSON with GSON or Jackson JSON